# Expired passports are .... so that they cannot be used

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

Which is the correct answer for the following test question.

> Expired passports are ..... so that they cannot be used.

1.Invalidated

2.Nullified

I saw both words can be used on the Internet.So I want to ask if  this question legitimate? If it is , what is the reason to pick out one another.

Only thing I spot on the internet that maybe

Expired passports are invalidated but Stolen/ Lost passports are nullified.

Comment: _"Cancelled"_ is another possibility.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer would be *invalidated* but the reasoning is quite subtle. Invalidated would implies the passport changes status from a valid one to an invalid one.

Nullify means to make into *null*, or nothing, a void. The passport still exists so cannot be said to have been nullified. One could nullify an action, such as nullifying a false vote, but we would  not normally say we had nullified an object.